# What does `>>` mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this code

```
sample1 >> sample2
```

What does it mean by `>>`?

Comment: what are `sample1` and `sample2`?

Comment: LOL. I meant what [data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)? :D

Comment: If these are integers, you might find this introduction to bit operators useful: http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/

Comment: does it have to be integer?

Comment: @RexAdrivan - no, it's just a method that can also appear as an operator. So Ruby calls `sample1.>>( sample2 )` - and that could do *anything* to either object. It would be useful to show what they are e.g. `p [sample1.class, sample2.class]`

Comment: It depends what `sample1` and `sample2` are. The `<<` and `>>` operators are [*usually*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) used for bit-shifting, but consider the following example: `class Example; def >>(b); puts b; end; end; Example.new >> 'Hello!'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Binary Right Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

```
a = 0b00111100
# => 60
a >> 2 
# => 15, which is 00001111
```

Comment: Note that some data types use the `<<` or `>>` operators for [different things](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Comment: @GoBusto, Yes, but does `>>` have any other usage?

Comment: In Ruby, anything that has been coded on the method. The variable names in the OP hint that something else might be going on. But this answer I think covers the only option in core Ruby.